# Drawing random lines in a cylinder - How does the distribution of angles look like?

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have a 3D cylinder with a radius of $r = 1$ and a height of $h = 2$.

[image]

Now, we pick two random points on the edges of the cylinder - one for the top and one for the bottom circle. By connecting the two dots with a line what we can do next is calculate the angle between the line and the vertical z-axis.

We repeat this procedure $N$-times and collect all the random angles.

What can we say for sure?

- The minimum angle should be $0$°, the case where we pick two points laying on top of each other giving us a parallel line to the z-axis.
- The maximum angle should be $45$° - which is decided for us by $r$ and $h$.

---

My question here is what distribution of angles we should get. Running an experiment will give me the following distribution:

[image]

Which is a bit counter intuitive - at least to me - I expected a uniform distribution to be honest. So, I do hope I did not make a mistake in my code, which is why I provide the experiment code below.

In any case I would be interested in whether this distribution makes sense and if it's possible to explain it.

One thing that surely is important: `np.random.rand()` draws uniform values $x \in [0,1]$ so the points on the edges (`v` and `w`) should be uniform too.

```
%matplotlib inline  # Jupyter Notebooks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def angle(a, b):    
    a_u = a / np.linalg.norm(a)
    b_u = b / np.linalg.norm(b)    
    c = np.clip(np.dot(a_u, b_u), -1, 1)    
    return np.degrees(np.arccos(c))

# Create the random points on the cylinder's edges
N = 5000
a = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(N) 
b = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(N)
v = np.vstack([np.cos(a), np.sin(a), 2*np.ones(N)]).T
w = np.vstack([np.cos(b), np.sin(b), np.zeros(N)]).T
df_v = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df_w = pd.DataFrame(w, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
# Get the connecting lines
df_u = df_v - df_w

# Calculate the angles of the lines w.r.t. the z-axis
e3 = np.asarray([0, 0, 1])
ds_angles = df_u.apply(lambda x: angle(x, e3), 1)

# Plotting the distribution of angles
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4.5)).gca()
sns.distplot(df_u.apply(lambda x: angle(x, e3), 1), ax=ax, kde=False)
plt.xlabel('Degree')
plt.show()
```

Comment: A way to gain intuition: Without loss of generality, fix a point on the bottom circle. There is a big range of points on the top circle that give angles close to $45^\circ$. However, to get an angle close to $0^\circ$ the top point must be very nearly right on top of the bottom point.

Comment: @Rahul Indeed, after reading Fimpellizieri's first argument it made sense to me. Also in the meantime a colleague of mine pointed out that one could imagine to project lines from a straight line into a half circle. Intuitively speaking, there are "more points" which might relate to a larger angle and fewer points which result in a smaller angle. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the point in the circle below, and $Y$ denote the point in the circle above.
For any given $X$, with probability $1/2$ we would have that $Y$ lies in the semi-circle whose midpoint is directly above $X$.

This means with probability $1/2$, the angle lies between $0$ and $\arccos(2/\sqrt6)\simeq 35.26^{\circ}$.
Hence, the assumption that the distribution of the angles would be uniform is flawed, and about half the time the angles should lie between $35.26^{\circ}$ and $45^{\circ}$ (which is far from half of the possible angles).

---

Here's an attempt at calculating things more explicitly.
Let $X, Y$ be uniform in the circle $C=\left\{(x,y,0)\in\mathbb R^3\,|\,x^2+y^2=1\right\}$.
Your random line has direction $\big(Y+(0,0,2)\big) - X$.
With $W = Y-X$, $h=(0,0,2)$ and $Z$ the cosine of the angle between that line an the $z$-axis, we have

$$Z = \frac{\langle W+h, (0,0,1)\rangle}{\lVert W+h\rVert} = \frac2{\lVert W+h\rVert}.$$

This implies

$$Z^2 = \frac{4}{4 + {\lVert W\rVert}^2} = \frac1{1+{\left\lVert\frac{W}2\right\rVert}^2}.$$

If $\theta_1,\theta_2 \sim \text{Unif}([0,2\pi])$, then $X\sim \big(\cos(\theta_1),\sin(\theta_1)\big)$ and $Y\sim \big(\cos(\theta_2),\sin(\theta_2)\big)$ so that $W\sim\big(\cos(\theta_1)-\cos(\theta_2),\sin(\theta_1)-\sin(\theta_2)\big)$.
Hence,

\begin{align}
{\left\lVert\frac{W}2\right\rVert}^2
&\sim
\frac14\left(
\underbrace{(\cos\theta_1)^2+(\cos\theta_2)^2}_1-2\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2
+
\underbrace{(\sin\theta_1)^2+(\sin\theta_2)^2}_1-2\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2
\right)
\\&=
\frac14\left(
2 - 2\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 - 2\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2
\right)
\\&=
\frac12\big(
1 - (\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2 + \sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2)
\big)
\\&=
\frac12\big(
1 - \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)
\big)
=
\frac12 - \frac{\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)}2
.
\end{align}

Therefore

$$Z^2 \sim \frac{2}{3-\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)}.$$

Observing that $Z\geq 0$, it follows that the angle $\alpha$ is distributed as

$$\alpha \sim \arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3-\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)}}\right),$$

where $\theta_1,\theta_2 \sim \text{Unif}([0,2\pi])$.
From here on, we can calculate $\mathbb P(\alpha \leq x)$ for $0<x<\pi/4$ as some area in the square $[0,2\pi]^2$ contained in the $\theta_1$-$\theta_2$ plane.

Alternatively, we can observe that $\Theta = \theta_1-\theta_2$ has pdf with support in $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ given by

$$f_{\Theta}(z) =
\left\{\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{2\pi+z}{4\pi^2}&&&-2\pi\leq z <0\\
\frac{2\pi-z}{4\pi^2}&&&0\leq z \leq 2\pi
\end{array}\right.
$$

Then, some algebraic manipulations show that

$$\mathbb P(\alpha \leq x)
=
\mathbb P\left(\cos(\Theta) \geq 3-\frac{2}{{\cos(x)}^2}\right)
.$$

Using the pdf above, we can calculate this explicity in terms of integrals that simplify to

$$\mathbb P(\alpha \leq x)
=
\frac{1}{\pi}\,\arccos\left(3-\frac{2}{{\cos(x)}^2}\right)
.$$

The density function $f_\alpha$ of $\alpha$ has support in $[0,\pi/4]$, and [according to Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+arccos(+3-2%2F(+(cos(x))%5E2))) we have (after simplifications considering its support) that it equals

$$f_{\alpha}(z) = \frac{2}{\pi}\,\frac{1}{\cos(z)\,\sqrt{\cos(2z)}},$$

which is way simpler than I expected, to be honest.
Observe that it's indeed a probability density function, in that it is non-negative and its integral is $1$.

Your histogram does somewhat resemble the area under $f_{\alpha}$, as you can verify [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(2%2Fpi+*+1%2F(cos(x)+*+sqrt(cos(2x))),+x%3D0..pi%2F4)), so this looks more like a case of 'wrong intuition' than of 'wrong code'.

---

I must point out that this sheds light to yet another rather curious identity involving $\pi$:

> $$\int_{\sqrt{2}/2}^1\,\,\,\frac{1}{u\,\sqrt{2u^2-1}\,\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\,\,du = \frac\pi2$$
>   $${}$$
>   $$\int_{1/2}^1\,\,\,\frac{1}{u\,\sqrt{2u-1}\,\sqrt{1-u}}\,\,\,du = \pi$$

Comment: I am always very impressed when I see somebody with the ability to write something like this down. :) Your first argument that 50% of the angles should lie between $0$ and  $\arccos(2/\sqrt{6})\approx 35.26$° makes total sense of course. I am particularly happy to see that the distribution looks like the histogram from the experiment. Thank you for your answer and the detailed elaboration. I guess tonight I'll sit down and try to *fully* understand this :) May I ask how long it took you to come up with this?

Comment: Well, I didn't work continuously on this throughout the day, but I'd say a couple of hours or three? More than I'd hoped for haha, but it was an interesting problem. The initial observation that it was clearly not uniform didn't take much long, but there was plenty of room to dig deeper.

Comment: Cool - I just was curious how long this takes :) Glad you had fun doing it!

Comment: Oh, I certainly did. Thanks for the interesting problem. =)

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZBwsm6B280&ab_channel=Numberphile) made me think of this problem again. :D

Comment: @StefanFalk Yeah, that's a pretty cool paradox! [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4139) approaches it in an interesting way.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to find the closed form for the cdf. The angle is
$$A = \arccos \frac
 {((\cos v, \sin v, 1) - (\cos u, \sin u, -1)) \cdot (0, 0, 1)}
 {| (\cos v, \sin v, 1) - (\cos u, \sin u, -1) |} =
\arccos \sqrt {\frac 2 {3 - \cos(v - u)}}.$$
Switching to $\xi = v + u, \eta = v - u$, the cdf is
$$\operatorname P(A < x) = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_\eta^{4\pi - \eta}
 \frac 1 {(2 \pi)^2} [A < x] d\xi d\eta \overset * = \\
\int_0^\pi
 \frac 2 {(2 \pi)^2} (4\pi - 2\pi) [A < x] d\eta = \\
\frac 1 \pi \int_0^\pi [\eta \lt \arccos(3 - 2 \sec^2 x)] d\eta = \\
\frac 1 \pi \arccos(3 - 2 \sec^2 x),$$
where $[\text {condition}]$ is $1$ if the condition is true and $0$ otherwise. For $*$, $f$ is symmetric around $\pi$, therefore $\int_0^{2\pi} \eta f(\eta) d\eta = 2 \pi \int_0^\pi f(\eta) d\eta$.

Comment: Thanks to you too Maxim for shedding light on this. :)